Adding a column to the right of a table with an unknown number of columns
I have a two tables (one is 1.csv, the other is 2.csv). The first one consists of names and scores like...
name,score
Alice,6
Bob,1
Joe,2
John,7
Michel,9

The other one has a table with not constant number of columns (sometime only one column, sometime two, sometimes three..) like...
Alice, Bob,
Michel,
Joe,John

I would like to add a new score column just right to the name field to allot his/her scores.
So, the desired results are,
Alice,6,Bob,1
Michel,9
Joe,2,John,7

How to implement this? I prefer an awk/bash script to do this task. Thanks in advance,
I tried to run the following script,
#!/bin/bash

declare -A scores
while IFS=',' read -r name score
do
    scores["$name"]=$score
done < 1.csv

while IFS=',' read -r -a names
do
    for name in "${names[@]}"
    do
        name=$(echo "$name" | xargs)
        echo -n "$name,${scores[$name]},"
    done
    echo
done < 2.csv

I was expecting a result like,
Alice,6,Bob,1
Michel,9
Joe,2,John,7

It seemed OK in this MWE case, but for bigger tables, it does no longer works.
How should I improve?

what do you mean by bigger tables? more rows? more columns? something else?  how does this code 'no longer work'? error? wrong answer? hangs? something else?

what happens if a name exists in 2.csv but not in 1.csv?

the reason of horizontal spread is a grouping according to the projects. I think it is OK if every person only attends to one single project, but worry the cases a person attends to several projects. Is it OK even in such a case. Also I worry about the case that score has an order larger than unity, say 23.

You not only want to add the score a a new column after each name. You also apparently want to suppress leading blanks in the name fields: in your example 2.csv there is a space before Bob in Alice, Bob,, but there is no space in your expected result. And you apparently also want to suppress empty fields at the end of each record in 2.csv: in Alice, Bob, and Michel, there is a trailing comma, but not in your expected output. Please edit your question and add the missing specifications (or fix your examples).

CSV is not a well specified format. Please edit your question and add the missing information: do you have quoted fields with commas in them, can you have newlines inside quoted fields, etc. And also explain what you want if a person is listed several times in 1.csv with different scores (or state that this cannot happen).

i appreciate your comments.

"it does no longer works" tells us nothing about the problem so it's hard to help you given that and no sample input/output with which we could reproduce the problem. Do divide-and-conquer on your large input that has the problem until you end up with a minimal version of it that still has the problem and then post a version of the input/output using that as your minimal reproducible example.
Having said that, if you want to do this using bash and mandatory POSIX tools (i.e. no python, perl, ruby, etc.) then you wouldn't use a bash while-read loop as in your script at all, see why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice, the bash part would just be to call a single awk script to do the rest, see whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk for how to parse CSV with awk in general but the following may be adequate for your needs given the sample input you provided, using any POSIX awk:
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
    BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }
    {
        sub(/\r$/,"")
        for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
            gsub(/[[:space:]]+/," ",$i)
            gsub(/^ | $/,"",$i)
        }
    }
    NR == FNR {
        if ( NR > 1 ) {
            name2score[$1] = $2
        }
        next
    }
    {
        sub(FS"$","")
        for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
            printf "%s%s%d%s", $i, OFS, name2score[$i]+0, (i<NF ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
' 1.csv 2.csv


$ ./tst.sh
Alice,6,Bob,1
Michel,9
Joe,2,John,7

If you don't have a POSIX awk then change this:
        gsub(/[[:space:]]+/," ",$i)
        gsub(/^ | $/,"",$i)

to this:
        gsub(/[ \t]+/," ",$i)
        sub(/^ /,"",$i); sub(/ $/,"",$i)

and then it'll work in any awk if the only mid-line spaces in your input are blanks and tabs, which is probably the case.

thanks very much for your answer. My thinking is now being updated and I am now trying to set an additional table allowing the Excel v-look-up function instead of inserting a cell right-hand side. My testing works well.
